# Bootstrap Jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I align the button within jumbotron, I want it to stick to the bottom of the jumbotron? I know that text-center, centers button/text, but I want it to also be at the moment of the content.

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:#; background-image: url('img/jumbo-bg.png'); background-position: 50% 50%; height:600px;">
        <a href="#register" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">Register</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post the code you are trying to use and describe what is not working please.

Comment: Added code and basically I want the " Register " button, to fall at the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<a href="#register" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" style="position:relative; top:500px">Register</a>
```

The position of the  element is now relative to the top property within the parent.